# Issue With Angular Hydration

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, hydration

I recently started a new Angular 17 project and I'm encountering a bit of an issue with server side rendering and/or hydration, not 100% sure which. Up until now I've primarily worked with lower versions (up to 14) and without server side rendering, so I have yet to encounter such an issue.

Within my home page component I subscribe to a Subject as provided by the `angular-requests` library. This means that I have an open observable, which causes the `ApplicationRef`'s `isStable` to not fire resulting in the page needing to wait 10 seconds to load (after which I am also given the following warning: `Angular hydration expected the ApplicationRef.isStable() to emit true, but it didn't happen within 10000ms. Angular hydration logic depends on the application becoming stable as a signal to complete hydration process. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0506`).

Reading through the link it suggests to subscribe to these observables using `NgZone` and subscribing outside of Angular, but I wouldn't want to force that within every single component that causes a request to be sent, as well as that feeling like a bad idea. This page did lead me managing to find a pretty hacky fix, but I feel like there must be some better way that allows me to have open subscriptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hacky Fix:

```js
app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  public canRender: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    inject(ApplicationRef).isStable
      .subscribe(isStable => this.canRender = isStable || this.canRender);
  }
}
```

```html
app.component.html

@if (canRender) {
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
}
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance,

Venfi

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to get as a result. SSR runs the app and does all the logic, so if some request takes more than 10 seconds to complete it is doubtful that it should run on the server side. Maybe you want to run this kind of logic on the server but only on the client after the rest of the app is rendered and you can show a nice loader?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
My issue isn't that the requests are taking more than 10 seconds (they take a few milliseconds), it's that due to an observable having an open subscription, the server side rendering never considers the application stable.

Comment: I did not get it then, observables complete when a request resolves. And if the zone does not become stable after that, most likely there is some timer or interval that runs in the background.